# Simple Foreach Image Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I receive all user activities for each image upload they make, but I also want to receive the image in this foreach along with the table.

In my database I have 5 columns within the `users` table, which are `doc1` `doc2` `doc3` `doc4` and `doc5`. As I receive the image made by them together with the correct description, without having to log in to each user account

[image]

in fact there are 5 controllers of these, please don't notice the mess ^^ I'm new to programming

```
 public function mudar_doc1(Request $request) {
    // getting all of the post data
            $file = array('image' => Input::file('image'));
    // setting up rules
            $rules = array('image' => 'required|image',); //mimes:jpeg,bmp,png and for max size max:10000
    // doing the validation, passing post data, rules and the messages
            $validator = Validator::make($file, $rules);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
    // send back to the page with the input data and errors
                return Redirect::to('userp')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
            } else {
    // checking file is valid.
                if (Input::file('image')->isValid()) {
                    $destinationPath = 'uploads'; // upload path
                    $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension

                    $extensoes = array("png", "jpeg", "jpg", "gif");
                    $resVal = in_array($extension, $extensoes);
                    if ($resVal) {

                    } else {
                        Session::flash('error', 'O upload não foi realizado com sucesso.');
                        return Redirect::to('userp');
                    }

                    $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $extension; // renameing image
                    Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $fileName); // uploading file to given path
                    $doc1 = asset($destinationPath . '/' . $fileName);
                    User::where('id', \Auth::user()->id)->update(['doc1' => $doc1]);
    // sending back with message
                    Session::flash('success', 'ID Card Front Successfully Added!');
                    \App\RegistroAtividade::addAtividade('Cartao ID Frente');

                    return Redirect::to('userp');
                } else {
    // sending back with error message.
                    Session::flash('error', 'O upload não foi realizado com sucesso.');
                    return Redirect::to('userp');
                }
            }
        }


               <tbody>
                @foreach($allAtividades as $atividade)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$atividade['id']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$atividade->getUser()->name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$atividade['ip']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$atividade['description']}}</td>
                    <td>{{$atividade['created_at']}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see much reference in your code for the Image / controller / view or data, please update your question and i will update this answer along

---

### Some important note I would like to make

- I would suggest you spare some time reading about the [Eloquent Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships)
- Then you can create the `Actividade` Eloquent if you don't have it already
- In `Actividade` Eloquent you can assign a `user` relations like so

```php
Class Actividade {

    //...
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

The user method here will return the user by using the user_id column in the `actividade` table  [if you have it set up correctly already], that will make it easier to fetch the user for activities `$actividade->user->name`, instead of `$actividade->getUser()->name;`

following this approach you can have an ImagesEloquent class having `activities` method which is relational just like activities having users and users having activities:

using this approach (skeleton) would be as easy as this:

```
@foreach(Image::find(1)->activities as $_activity){
  <td><img src="{{Image::find(1)->filename}}"/></td> <!-- just an example here -->
  <td>{{$_activity->id}}</td>
  <td>{{$_activity->user->name}}</td>
  <td>{{$_activity->ip}}</td>
  <td>{{$_activity->description}}</td>
  <td>{{$_activity->created_at}}</td>
@endforeach
```

*You fetch the Image, you can fetch it's activities, and then each activity has users*

It will take a bit of time (an hour or so) to learn about this, but will save you hundreds of hours in the future and get you a way cleaner code, i thought to suggest that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206483/discussion-on-answer-by-emad-simple-foreach-image-laravel).